# Remove after the ? symbol. Needed for Excel

Tags: regex, excel, spreadsheet

I Want to remove only `?gxt=12sadbsaj=1235\&&&*` from `https://www.choicehotels.com/georgia/decatur/quality-inn-hotels/ga908?gxt=12sadbsaj=1235\&&&*`. How can I do that using regex?

Comment: Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `=left(input, find("?", input))`. You might need a + or - 1 in there somewhere. But that'll take the leftmost characters up to the result of the find which will give the number of characters up to the ?.

Comment: Btw, you asked for regex which is only really available by VBA (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops). A regex to match everything up to the '?' would be something like '[^\?]*'. That would match all non-question mark characters from the beginning.

Comment: I've found a similar question: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/556799-use-a-formula-to-delete-part-of-a-text-string.html  with the following solution: =LEFT(A2,SEARCH("?",A2)-1) A2 being the cell in which the full string is ;)

Comment: =LEFT(A2,SEARCH("?",A2)-1) , Search didn't worked for me in spreadsheet but instead of Search FIND worked out perfectly. Thanks a lot